# Pure CSS parallaxing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place the blue as a parallax background behind the gray and the brown footer.

Currently I have this:

```
<div class="description-container">Here</div>
<div class="parallax-bottom" />
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

But as you can see, the order is still reversed and has the footer showing up on top of the parallaxed blue div.

This is the CSS I have:

```
.parallax-bottom {
    background-color: brown;
    min-height: 500px;
    
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue and whether you liked my suggestion or do I need to ameliorate my skills and suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have not closed the `div` tag correctly.

`<div class="parallax-bottom"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Close your div tag correctly and it will work perfectly.

And I have a suggestion for you that next time you code use **Viewport Units** like **vw** and **vh** instead of **px** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.